# Defining a Stereotype for a non-UML element in a Sparx Enterprise Architect UML Profile does not seem to work

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I am trying to create a UML profile that extends a `SysML1.3::block` element. I used the profile helper to create a profile package and its sub-packages for *UML profile* and the *Toolbox profile*. Saving, generating and loading the profile works and the corresponding toolbox is shown in the *Toolbox*.

## Error Message

However, when I drag the element from the toolbox onto the diagram I get the following error message:

> ---
>
> ### Enterprise Architect
>
> Missing base type: 'MyBlockStereo1' does not extend 'SysML1.3::block'
>
> ### Command: MetaModel::MyBlockStereo1(SysML1.3::block)
>
> ### [ OK ]

The following figure shows the visual representation of the actual error message:

[image: Error message when dropping element onto diagram]

## Question

How do I define a stereotype that derives from a non-UML element and how can I include such a stereotype in a toolbox so I can drag it onto a diagram?

Thanks for your help!

## Additional information

I am using Enterprise Architect 14.1 and followed the description from [Create Stereotypes Extending non-UML Objects](https://sparxsystems.com.au/resources/user-guides/modeling/mdg-technologies.pdf)

Here is a visual representation of the defined profile:

[image: Toolbox Profile: Icon definition]

[image: UML Profile: Stereotype definition]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the manual that is exactly how you have to extend existing non-UML stereotype since v14.

But I had the same problem you have. I managed to solve it by using the "old" way where you needed to generalize the non-UML stereotype, but also had to extend the base metatype.

In my case that was with ArchiMate:

[image]

The toolbox then uses the metaclass `(UML::Class)`

[image]

This seemed to work just fine. I never bothered trying to figure out what was really going on as I had a perfectly functional workaround.

Comment: Enterprise Architect: the work around tool. What a great slogan that would be.

Comment: You can also use an Association with stereotype=extends instead of the Extension connector which then provides traceability i.e. selecting the ToolBoxPage, (meta)Class will show what's connected to the selected element. There is a long-lived bug for the Extension connector where traceability isn't shown when this connector is used.